# Changing user Privileges on a Database Informix

Tags: informix

How can I change a user privileges on a database, on all tables from consult to select, delete, update, insert, in Informix.

I tried to use something like this

```
dbaccess DATABASE exec for i in (select table_name from user_tables) loop execute immediate 'grant select,insert,update,delete on '||i.table_name||' to USER'; end loop
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB-Access isn't my favourite tool, but it can do the job with some support from a shell script.  You end up invoking it twice, once to generate the list of table names and once to process the permissions.

Given the file `so-6952-3871.sql` containing:

```sql
unload to '/dev/stdout'
    select tabname
       from "informix".systables
      where tabid >= 100
        and tabtype = 'T';
```

the shell script `so-6952-3871.sh` does the job, revoking existing privileges and granting new ones:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# @(#)$Id$
#
# Grant select, insert, delete, update permission on all user tables in a database to a named user.

: "${DBACCESS:=dbaccess}"

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "$0: you must specify the database and at least one user" >&2
    echo "Usage: $0 database user [...]" >&2
fi
dbase="$1"
shift
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo "$0: must specify at least one user" >&2
    echo "Usage: $0 database user [...]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

$DBACCESS $dbase so-6952-3871.sql |
sed -n '/^\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)|$/ s//\1/p' |
while read tabname
do
    #echo "Table: $tabname" >&2
    for user in "$@"
    do
        echo "revoke all on $tabname from $user;"
        echo "grant select, insert, delete, update on $tabname to $user;"
    done
done |
$DBACCESS $dbase -
```

I've chosen to use the `"informix".systables` system catalog table since I don't have a table called `user_tables` in my database.  You can refine the selection criteria (for example, to omit the time series tables) as necessary.

Provided you have sufficient permissions to grant and revoke permissions in the database (e.g. as the DBA or as user `informix`), this should work OK.

Rather than use DB-Access, I'd use my SQLCMD (available from the [IIUG Software
Archive](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL)), which
I wrote to behave consistently in shell scripting contexts whereas
DB-Access doesn't.
It dates back to 1986 (before there was `dbaccess`; in those days, you
used `isql` instead — DB-Access was carved out of `isql` in an
evening).
It bears no relation to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the
same name — except for the name and having the same general purpose
(manipulate SQL databases).  With SQLCMD, there'd be no need for the `sed` line to ignore noise output from DB-Access on standard output.

Comment: thank you so much it works and it really helps and really thank you for the software archive.